# Go library and example for generating code based on template

Tags: go, templates

I have a few java classes with default names that can be used as templates. I want to generate java classes of different names by simply replace the names in those templates.
How can I achieve that in Go? Any examples? Thanks.
For example,
I have:
HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld {
}
```

I want to generate other classes like
Example1.java

```
public class Example1 {
}
```

in my Go code.
The tool is used by other developers to generate some templated code for their own services.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements; do you want to open a file, read it's contents, replace one string with another (e.g. "HelloWorld" -> "Example1") and [save to a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789882/read-a-text-file-replace-its-words-output-to-another-text-file)? Or is it more complex than that e.g. you want to use [data driven templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) or parse the Java so you are only replacing function names and ignore other uses of the string?

Comment: Thanks. We are trying to open a few files, read their contents, replace some strings with others, and save them to new files. In kotlin, there is a library called MustacheFactory. I am wondering what is the Go equivalent library. Any examples would be great. Thanks.

Comment: if you use vscode you can setup snippets

Comment: The standard library includes [templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and is well documented. There are also a few mustache implementations ([here](https://github.com/hoisie/mustache) and [here](https://github.com/alexkappa/mustache)).